# Using countif() with filtered view Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm wondering how I would use countif() with a filtered sheet that has conditional formatting. The sheet paints cells containing certain text red, and the filter only shows the cells that have been painted.

Using countif as is counts all data, how do I get it to only count visible data? I know I can use a helper column to assign each values but how would I do that if the formatting changes over time? IE: I change the condition from searching for "Tree Logs" to "Branches" resulting is a different group of cells being shown.

Comment: Note that the Sheets tag says `avoid use with [excel]` (and the excel tag says to not use with other spreadsheet programs).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized example of how you can get the count of just the filtered data using [SUBTOTAL()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649?hl=en)

- On the left side of screenshot is the full sample data table and when
  I do the `=COUNTIF(A:A,"DEF")` it results in `5` irrespectve of
  whether its filtered or aint.
- Now with the inclusion of `subtotal` function along with `countifs`
  as below you can get the count of just the visible data

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"DEF",map(A:A,lambda(z,subtotal(103,z))),1)`

[image]

Comment: OR if you just want the count of visible `Column A` filtered by color data; you can just try: `=subtotal(103,A2:A)`

Comment: This works perfectly! Would you be able to tell me how I would format the data in a separate sheet? 

Sheet 1 = Houses the data
Sheet 2 = Houses the formula

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: [Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BI9fjS2PyD3QVI6YwJ3Ntt0iv0Bv6Fmxr4uTrs0p1Ps/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Lets say if cell `A1` in `Counting Total Results` tab has the `DopamineExpress` then formula would be `=COUNTIFS('Filter and Condition Searching for specific names'!A:A,"*by "&A1&"*",map('Filter and Condition Searching for specific names'!A:A,lambda(z,subtotal(103,z))),1)`

Comment: Nevermind, I was referencing the wrong sheet. Thank you so much for your help!